# How to turn UITextField user input into a usable pointer to a dictionary key?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, uitextfield, nsdictionary

I am trying to take a user input in a UIText field and turn it into a pointer that will access a dictionary key and then return the corresponding value for use in an equation. I feel like I am in the ballpark but I can't figure out how to make it work.

The keys are going to be float values, and the user input is the key itself. I realize that sounds confusing. Here's an example: The user inputs 44.25 in the UITextField. I need this user input to find the 44.25 key in my dictionary and then return the corresponding value associated with that key that will then plug into a simple equation.

Here is my code calling the dictionary (which works) and my attempt at making a pointer out of the input, which does not work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myDictionary" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];



float inches = [self.inchesText.text floatValue];
NSLog(@"%.2f", apples);

NSLog(@"There are %@ oranges", MyDictionary [apples]);
```

Comment: Something like `someObject = [myDictionary objectForKey:myTextField.text];` should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the text from your text field and use it in a call to ojectForKey. Make sure you code for the (likely) case where the user-entered key can't be found in the dictionary and you get back a nil.

The code is dirt simple, and might look something like this:

```
NSString *key = self.inchesText.text;
NSString *value = myDictionary[key];

if (value == nil)
   //Tell the user they entered an invalid key
else
   //Do whatever you need to do with the fetched value.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will give this a shot and respond with how it worked out.

Comment: OK. So I was able to get the text input to call the value from the dictionary (Thank you!!!) but I need to be able to use the values called in a mathematical equation. I know that strings can't be used in math (I don't think so anyway), and I am getting an error to the following effect: _Arithmetic on pointer to interface 'NSString', which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform_  I will put my code in a separate comment since it will not fit here.

Comment: The code I am using is: `NSString *startKey = self.startLevel.text;
    NSString *startValue = chart[startKey];
   
    NSString *stopKey = self.stopLevel.text;
    NSString *stopValue = chart[stopKey];
   
    NSLog(@"%@", startValue);
    NSLog(@"%@", stopValue);
    NSString *volume = stopValue - startValue;`

Comment: I have tried changing the strings to NSNumbers across the board, but that doesn't work either. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Any tips for getting my values into a math equation? Thanks.

Comment: Figured this out finally after a bit more research. This is what's up: `// Turns the string values into doubles that can be used in the equation`
    `double startValueDbl = [startValue doubleValue];
    double stopValueDbl = [stopValue doubleValue];`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know all keys for NSDictionaries need to be objects, not primitives.  That being said you could create an object around your primitive with `NSNumber` objects.

I don't think that would help you though.  Since you are reading the `NSDictionary` straight from file I would assume they are being read into the Dictionary as `NSString` values (@"44.25" instead of the number 44.25).  If that is the case then you could just pass the pointer to the textfield.text to retrieve your desired Dictionary element (assuming the text is equal to one of your dictionary keys in the file).

Comment: What would that code look like? the text input is going to be forced to integers using the number pad  plus .0, .25, .5, ,75 using a segmented control - I haven't figured out how to make that work; another question.